# How to read the Dual optimal solution from the terminal tableau.

Tags: optimization, linear-programming, simplex

I have a terminal tableau and I know that it is easy to get the primal optimal solution but how can i get a dual optimal solution from the tableau.

My tableau is below:
[image]

My notation is slightly diferent. The values at the top refer to -S<sub>N</sub>  = -C<sub>N</sub> <sup>T</sup> + C<sub>B</sub> <sup>T</sup>A<sub>B</sub> <sup>-1</sup>A<sub>N</sub>  and S<sub>B</sub>  = 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The optimal solution corresponds to the coefficients belonging to additional variables in the row for the objective function.